# Deal with XMLHttpRequest in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping the table of this kind of pages:

http://www.trulia.com/school-district/CA-San_Francisco_County/San_Francisco_Unified/

There is a table with several pages whose  change is through an  XMLHttpRequest, inspecting the page I can get te url for this request

http://www.trulia.com/q_schools_in_district.php?did=600116051&grade=elementary&page=2&sortby=testRating&sortdir=desc

But I can't scrape this url with scrapy

When I try:

```
scrapy shell http://www.trulia.com/q_schools_in_district.php?did=600116051&grade=elementary&page=2&sortby=testRating&sortdir=desc
```

I don't get response, how can this data be scraped?

Comment: surround url with `""`

Comment: It works,  why it's needed to use the "" for this page, and not for the original page http://www.trulia.com/school-district/CA-San_Francisco_County/San_Francisco_Unified/? could you explain this in a response to close the question.

Comment: because the second url contains `&` which is also recognized by shell to run another process.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez consider closing the question by accepting the community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*originally posted by eLRuLL in the comments*]

Surround your url with `""`, because the second url contains `&` which is also recognized by the shell to run another process.